# Error with Visual Studio 2012 for Web

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web, nopcommerce

I try to use nopCommerce sourse with Visual Studio 2012. I tried to start debugging and i've got this error:

Unable to launch the configured visual studio development web server.

[image: http://puu.sh/k0HSx/2983317043.png]

This sourses is original and they must work.

Comment: On my laptop it work with VS 2012.

Comment: try open VS as administrator

Comment: can you please translate the last part of the error?

Comment: I did face similar issue and ended up using iis.